# Why small amount of water in glass, moves along it's walls?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, experimental-physics

Many times I had noticed that when a small amount of water is left in glass, it always stays sticking to it's walls, whenever I move the glass, most of the water moves along the glass's walls. I think most of you had also noticed this.

> I want to know why does this happen?

Comment: why don't you read this http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/surten.html

Comment: It is due to adhesive forces between water and glass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the adhesive forces between the molecules of water and the glass. Adhesive forces are the attractive forces between unlike molecules. They are caused by forces acting between two substances, such as mechanical forces (sticking together) and electrostatic forces (attraction due to opposing charges). In the case of a liquid wetting agent, adhesion causes the liquid to cling to the surface on which it rests. When water is poured on clean glass, it tends to spread, forming a thin, uniform film over the glasses surface. This is because the adhesive forces between water and glass are strong enough to pull the water molecules out of their spherical formation and hold them against the surface of the glass, thus avoiding the repulsion between like molecules.